# Extend RequiredFields class and call it in another class in SilverStripe

Tags: validation, silverstripe

I have two classes: `MyAccountPage` and `PersonalData_Validator1`

```
class MyAccountPage extends Page {

    public function canCreate($member = null) {
        return false;
    }
}

class MyAccountPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'editprofile'
    );

    public function EditProfileForm(){

        $firstName = new TextField('FirstName', 'First Name *');
        $firstName->addExtraClass('requiredField form-control');

        $surName = new TextField('Surname', 'Last Name *');
        $surName->addExtraClass('requiredField form-control');

...

    $validator = new PersonalData_Validator1(array(
        $firstName,
        $surName
    ));

}
```

When I write `PersonalData_Validator1` class in the same page it works, but when I write `PersonalData_Validator1` in another page it doesn't work. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: It doesn't work ... any errors you get? Did you setup error logging? Without any information about the error you get we cannot help you!

Comment: it says no PersonalData_Validator1 class  found

Answer (score 1):

this is my PersonalData_Validator1 class

```
class PersonalData_Validator1 extends RequiredFields {

public function php($data){
    $bRet = parent::php($data);

    $err = false;

 $invalid_char = array("'","\"","*","%", "=", "`","<",">","@","^","$","     (",")");

    $pcrePattern = '[A-Za-z0-9]';
    $firstName=$data['FirstName'];
    $lastName=$data['Surname'];
    $nic=$data['NIC'];

    if($bRet){
        $pregSafePattern = str_replace('/', '\\/', $pcrePattern);

        if((!preg_match('/' . $pcrePattern . '/i', $firstName)) ){
            $this->validationError('FirstName', 'First Name contains invalid characters', 'validation');
            $err = true;
            //$bRet = true;
        }



       else if(( !preg_match('/' . $pcrePattern . '/i', $lastName))){
            $this->validationError('Surname', 'Last name contains invalid characters', 'validation');
            $err = true;
        }



         else if(($nic && !preg_match('/' . $pcrePattern . '/i', $nic))){
            $this->validationError('NIC', 'NIC field contains invalid characters', 'validation');
             $err = true;
        }


    }

    if($err == 'true'){
        $bRet = true;
    }else{
        //return $bRet;
    }
    return $bRet;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Which filename does the containing file have? The silverstripe class loader expects afaik the filename to reflect the classname. So you have to put your `PersonalData_Validator1` class in a file called `PersonalData` (everything before the underscore is important for the filename)

Comment: okii i removed the (_)undescore and replecd the file name as PersonalDataValidator1. so now class PersonalDataValidator1 is in the file PersonalDataValidator1.php  but still the error is as "Fatal error: Class 'PersonalDataValidator1' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\LKDR_48\build\mysite\code\Pages\MyAccount\MyAccountPage.php on line 108"

Comment: line 108 is ; "$validator = new PersonalDataValidator1(array(
        $firstName,
        $surName
    ));"

Comment: Did you flush? (add `?flush` to the url?) otherwise the new class will not be recognized by the class loader. Also don't pass an array of Field Objects but an array of FieldNames to it for required fields, e.g. `$validator = new PersonalDataValidator1(array( 'FirstName', 'SurName' ));`

Comment: yes i did ?flush. and corected the array but still no progress.

Comment: what's the file's path? is it also inside /mysite/code ? then it should be ok. maybe another typo, parsing error, whatever? any error logs you can look at or activate?

Comment: It says Fatal error: Class 'PersonalDataValidator1' not found. and yes it is in /mysite/code

Comment: heyy dude just found, my mistake. i have not named the class properly. thanks for the support